# Alternative for IRF520 mosfet in Arduino shutdown schema

Tags: power, arduino-nano, mosfet

I’am using IRF520 mosfet according to this [schema](https://www.zolalab.com.br/eletronica_projetos/auto_shutdown_enus.php) to shut down Arduino by low level on output to 10K ohms resistor

Schema of my device is[image]

---

The issue is that IRF520 took too much place

Is it possible to substitute IRF520 with smaller mosfet?

***Additional info:***

I measured average power consumption – it’s about 22 mA on 12V = 0.264W

IRF520 is for 70W max according to datasheets.

The base schema is

[image]

Comment: check out irlz44n much better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, any transistor, bjt or MOSFET, would work. 2n2222 or 7000 for example. Irf5x0 is actually a poor choice here. It only worked due to the low load being switched.

Comment: I going try 2N7000 - http://www.futurlec.com/Transistors/2N7000.shtml, since 200mA should be enought for my schema. What do you think about resistors? Should I change them or I can left 10K and 120K?

Comment: That transistor has a very high R_DSON. You should be looking for sub-ohm resistances.

Comment: @Majenko I'm not very good with mosfets, should I increase resistance of R1 or R2 for 2N7000?

Comment: No. Choose a different mosfet with a lower resistance.

Comment: No need to increase r1 r2. If anything they are already too big. 2n7000 or 2n7002 if you want even smaller devices is more than adequate for your application. Its rds is 6ohm max and if you look at the id vs. Vds chart it is even smaller for a Typical 2n7000. So people arguing for its high rds are reading the spec without understanding it.

Comment: I'll try 2N7000 and 2N7002, thanks. What do you think how much I should decrease R1 and R2 to make them work in my schema instead of IRF520?

Comment: R1 is there to prevent ringing / overloading the mcu and R2 to help bleed off the charge on the gate. they are useful only for high speed switching on big mosfet. the typical value for R1 is in the <10R range (with a driver). and R2 <1K. If you are switching at high speed (100Khz or over and pushpull), I would consider putting a 47 - 110R as R1 and go without R2.

Comment: After picking of the resistors I found that 2N7000 working well for my case with R1 = 10K and R2 = 5.6K. Also 2N7002 is a compact version of 2N7000 for surface mount. I will update my question by this information, thanks